# if statements in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I have been writing in c++ for a few weeks now and can't help but feel that I am using too many if statements in my code. I am aware of while, do while, and for loops but when given the scenario I always use if statements. I guess I am not exactly aware of how I could use a different method. I just finished a project and there are if statements everywhere. Could one of you guys please explain to me how I can change some of these if statements into something different but still functional? I am really just looking for guidance in the right direction. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you guys!

If statement #1 that bugs me:

```
    if (x >= 1)
    {
        setx_Position(3);
        sety_Position(500);
        cout << "Soldier moves: " <<getx_Position()<<", "<<gety_Position()<< "   ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Soldier moves: " <<getx_Position()<<", "<<gety_Position()<< "   ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Second if statement bugging me is :

```
    a--;
    if (a >= 0)
    {
        cout << "Soldier fires weapon : Pistol " << "(" << a << " bullets left)" << endl;
    }
    else if (x <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Soldier fires weapon : NO WEAPON FIRED! (DEAD)" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Both of these just feel lengthy and unnecessary to me. How could I get the same results with a much cleaner look? Or is this the best way to do it?

Comment: You have not provided this code within any context.  In particular the state variables.  It's pretty hard to advise.  I see very few `if` statements here.  If you're hung up on that, you should have a rethink about how far you want to take your programming pursuits =)

Comment: You can "factor" out the duplicate code from the first. It's going to run in either case. Getting the computer to make decisions is an integral part of program logic, though.

Comment: Agree with previous comments. You could hide some logic inside a class (this is C++ after all) but without seeing more context it's hard to tell you how.

Comment: Please change the title to something less emotional and more descriptive/to-the-point.

Comment: Change your question heading please

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry about the title. I changed it

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with having to use `if` statements, they're often a must when you need to perform an action conditionally. As for improving your snippets, an obvious thing to do in the first one is to move the common sections of code outside the `if-else` block.

```
if (x >= 1)
{
    setx_Position(3);
    sety_Position(500);
}
cout << "Soldier moves: " << getx_Position() << ", " << gety_Position() << "   ";
cout << endl;
```

The second one looks pretty good as is. The only thing I see that could (arguably) be an improvement is to remove `a--;` and change the `if` condition to `if(--a >= 0)`

Comment: Thanks Praetorian, I appreciate your time

Comment: I know it introduces the dreaded scrollbar, but @Dolbyover, the `endl` (or `'\n'`) could be placed at the end of the other output statement as well if you feel better about that being one line/statement.

Comment: ...or perhaps `if (a-- > 0)`. If a is a non-static local you can even get away with `if (a > 0)`.

Comment: For cleaner code, I'd suggest to handle position as a single object, instead of separate x and y. E.g. `set_position(3, 500);` and `cout << "Soldier moves" << get_position() << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, Turing would be proud for so much loyalty to the behaviour of the original Turing machine but in modern C++ there are other weapons in your arsenal, I suggest to read a book about patterns, maybe [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), there is not such thing as "optimizing" or suggest something starting from your snippets, it's merely pointless because a single if can't really impact on your productive skills, you need a foundation about advanced C++ techniques.

Answer (score 0):

well an if statement is a very common thing to use in code, especially in logic heavy sections, such as game code.

in c++ one way to avoid lots of if blocks for different things is to use Polymorphism, or function pointers.

switch statements can also be good.

I can't really see any better way of doing your two examples, except for the optimization of example one mentioned by Praetorian

Answer (score 0):

A great deal depends upon what sort of logic you're willing to use to avoid an `if` statement.

For example, let's consider your second example. You really have pretty much the same actions in both legs of the `if` statement -- you mostly just supply different data to write to the output. If you don't mind some minor changes in wording, it's pretty easy to eliminate the `if` statement entirely:

```
static char const *prefixes[] = {
    "Soldier tries to fire (but has ",
    "Soldier fires Weapon: Pistol ("
};

std::cout << prefixes[--a >= 0] << a << " bullets left)\n";
```

It's a little hard to say whether I'd recommend this or not. At first glance, the code is obviously a lot simpler and cleaner -- no conditions or `if` statements to deal with at all. At the same time, for somebody who's unaccustomed to this style, it would undoubtedly lead to some *serious* head-scratching.

Answer (score 0):

> please explain to me how I can change some of these if statements into
>   something different but still functional?

If you need to make decisions, you need if statements. Thing is, if you have many many of them littering the code I agree with you that you would want to think long and hard about how to make the code more readable by performing the logic in other ways. (Remember, (paraphrasing) code is mainly for reading; and only occasionally for the computer to execute). You probably don't want code that is too 'procedural', i.e. one long stream of C-like code. Create classes/objects that react to your simulation, thus encapsulating much of the logic. And please, don't have massively nested if/else spaghetti.

Another reason to reduce the number of if's is that if blocks are the most likely parts of your code to contain bugs, and are the hardest to test. (You are writing tests, right?)

But as others have said, there's not enough context. Oh, and name your variables like "NumBulletsRemaining" instead of x or whatever :)